# How to use Unity Dash in Gnome classic?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, gnome-classic

I am wondering if there is a way to use Unity Dashboard in Gnome-classic? If yes, what are the dependency packages need to be installed?

**UPDATE:**

Or is there any app could do that?

Comment: Nope you can't Unity is a compiz plug-in, the Dash being a part of Unity needs it to be active in the first place.SO no u can haz no Dash11!!1. :D

Comment: But, there's Slingshot Launcher

Comment: Look cool. Is it stable now? Any bug until now?

Comment: Stable, well it works 90% of the time, bugs yeah is at version 0.1.. one very annoying bug is that the launcher won't fit the screen.

Comment: Please Uri, just one more ques, what command to remove it in case I dont want to use it anymore?

Comment: apt-get purge( or instead can be just remove) slingshot-launcher , you have to add the elementary development PPA first of course.

Comment: you are wandering off topic - suggest change the question to say "are there any alternatives" - and allow @Uri to post an answer which you can vote on/accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There's Currently no way to use the Dash without Unity being active so here's an alternative.**

## [elementary's Slingshot.](https://launchpad.net/slingshot)

---

Slingshot launcher is developed by the Elementary team. Here is how to install Slingshot launcher in Ubuntu Natty from elementary team ppa.

---

[Add the PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/50965#50965) `ppa:elementaryart/elementary-dev` and install slingshot-launcher from the software center.

To use it you simply have to create a launcher in the Gnome Panel with the command `slingshot`, the same goes for AWN.

[image]

[Source.](http://ubuntuguide.net/install-slingshot-elementary-os-launcher-in-ubuntu-11-04-unity)

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 12.04, there is a way to get the Dash. However, this includes also enabling launcher.

Start `unity-2d-shell` as described here: [Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome Classic and Unity Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/q/261897/55343)

You will get the unity launcher, from which you can open the dash. Or use the `super/windows` key.

For autohiding the launcher in 12.04 see this question: [Autohide Unity Launcher in Gnome Classic](https://askubuntu.com/q/262585/55343).

Answer (score -4):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but it is possible to run gnome-panel and Unity at the same time. Just don't use the upper gnome-panel, because that will create conflicts with the Unity panel. So just delete the upper panel and add gnome-panel to your startup applications, and you will have both.

Comment: He wants Unity dash , not the panel.  And he is in classic gnome desktop so he has the `gnome-panel` by default.

Comment: Whether you use Gnome Panel with Unity, or Unity with Gnome Panel.. What's the difference?

Comment: Big difference. The OP is asking how to get only [Unity Dash](http://omgubuntu.co.uk/natty/#dash) in the classic desktop , not in the unity desktop. He wasn't asking how to get gnome-panel beside unity(i.e the launcher+the panel+the dash).